# Medium splash page in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Recently, Twitter founders have set up a new cool social media publishing called https://medium.com/

My first thought was: *oh, wow, how this guys have done this goodly splash page?*

So, my silly question: is there a fast and simple way to do something similar with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think you would need Bootstrap just to make such a page. Just plain HTML and CSS is enough. Is there something specific that you have problems with?

Comment: It is defently **not** a "bootstrap-powered" website. BTW, the bootstrap-programmers no longer work at twitter, it has been a project for itself http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/09/29/onward/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems quite easy to me. If you look at the code (here a beatified version) :

```
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork" style="background-image:url('//dnqgz544uhbo8.cloudfront.net/_/fp/img/home/b.PJ4x7XRiSEPMkdWrQj2WbQ.jpg')">
    <div class="mask">
    </div>
    <div class="content page-splash">
      <div class="logo-terms">
        <a href="//medium.com/policy/9db0094a1e0f" class="tos">
          Our Terms of Service
        </a>
        <div class="logo">
          Medium
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <span class="quote">
          “
        </span>
        <span class="pull-quote">
          We’re rethinking publishing and building a new platform from scratch. This is a preview.
        </span>
        <span class="actions">
          <a href="//medium.com/about/9e53ca408c48">
            Read more
          </a>
          <span class="or">
            or
          </span>
          <a href="/m/account/authenticate-twitter">
            Sign in with Twitter&nbsp;
            <span class="twitter">
            </span>
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The important parts is the `body` `background-image` and the `mask`, CSS defined here >>> dnqgz544uhbo8.cloudfront.net/_/fp/css/splash-base.umkWq9wEC0rFHI0pblZljA.css <<<
 - `mask` is positioned width/height 100% above body with `z-index` 100 and a transparenting color #E3E3E1. The other items `quote`, `pull-quote` and `actions` is positioned above that (you can see their CSS-definitions in the mentioned link).

You will also need some pictures dimensioned to different resolutions / device types (like android phones), so you immediately can deliver a correct dimensioned image very fast, and insert to the body as background image when the page is loaded.

Edit  :Link is between >>> <<<, appearently SO's regex doesnt like the structure of the link (it gets messed of with http://)